# Символ & в свойстве CheckBox

Tags: c#, winforms

Как в описании CheckBox добавить символ &. В свойсте Text я добавляю, но на форме он не показывается.

Comment: [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-create-access-keys-with-windows-forms-label-controls)

Answer (score 6):

При установленном в *true* свойстве **UseMnemonic** символ амперсанда (&) в свойстве **Text** интерпретируется как ярлык для горячих клавиш "ALT+{Символ}.
Например, если для чекбокса в свойстве Text указать "&Фамилия", то на форме подпись у текстбокса будет выглядеть как "Фамилия", где буква **Ф** будет подчёркнута. Соответственно, комбинация горячих клавиш "ALT+Ф" будет переключать данный чекбокс.

Таким образом, при установленном в *true* свойстве **UseMnemonic** двойной символ амперсанда(&) в свойстве **Text** даст вам одинарный символ на форме.

Если же UseMnemomic установлено в *false*, то достаточно одинарного амперсанда в свойстве **Text**.

Comment: Не обязательно. Зависит от свойства `UseMnemonic`. Разверните ответ, дополните его.

Comment: Вот теперь хорошо!